# How to run a Maven project from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to run a simple Java project. I had created a project using the 'Maven Project' type. I have one main class called 'TestMain'. When I tried to run the project using right click -> run, there was no menu to run the application as 'Run As Java Application'. I am wondering where that option has gone.

Can anyone please help me to run the Java application?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, you need to incorporate `exec-maven-plugin`, this plug-in performs the same thing that you do on command prompt when you type in `java -cp .;jarpaths TestMain`. You can pass argument and define which phase (`test`, `package`, `integration`, `verify`, or `deploy`), you want this plug-in to call your main class.

You need to add this plug-in under `<build>` tag and specify parameters. For example

```
   <project>
    ...
    ...
    <build>
     <plugins>
      <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
       <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.1</version>
       <executions>
        <execution>
         <phase>test</phase>
         <goals>
          <goal>java</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
          <mainClass>my.company.name.packageName.TestMain</mainClass>
          <arguments>
           <argument>myArg1</argument>
           <argument>myArg2</argument>
          </arguments>
         </configuration>
        </execution>
       </executions>
      </plugin>
     </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
    ...
   </project>
```

Now, if you right-click on on the project folder and do `Run As > Maven Test`, or `Run As > Maven Package` or `Run As > Maven Install`, the `test phase` will execute and so your Main class.

Answer (score 3):

`(Alt + Shift + X) , then M` to Run Maven Build. You will need to specify the Maven goals you want on `Run -> Run Configurations`

Answer (score 1):

Your Maven project doesn't seem to be configured as a Eclipse Java project, that is the Java **nature** is missing (the little 'J' in the project icon).

To enable this, the `<packaging>` element in your pom.xml should be `jar` (or similar).

Then, **right-click the project and select *Maven > Update Project Configuration***

For this to work, you need to have m2eclipse installed. But since you had the _ New ... > New Maven Project_  wizard, I assume you have m2eclipse installed.