# Is there any tool in eclipse to run maven commands directly?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

Is there any tool/plugin for eclipse which allows to run the maven commands directly from the eclipse?

I have already added the M2E plugin to my eclipse which is allowing me to create/import and even able to run the Maven projects in Eclipse through the "Run As" configuration. For example, If I have added tomact7 plugin to my project then to execute "mvn tomcat:run" command on my project I must configure  this new command in "Run As" so likewise for each new command I must configure a **Run AS** option.

- But whereas in **IntelliJ** we have the *Maven tool* window where we can run any maven command directly on the project instead of any configuration

So in Eclipse also I want to execute/run maven commands directly instead of configuring the **Run As** for each new command

**NOTE:**

1)We can configure the maven commands by "Run As" option but I don't want to do that

2)Even I don't want to use MS Dos cmd.exe configuration option in Eclipse by external tools also

Thanks in advance!

**Regards,**
Baji

Comment: First why don't you like to use "Run As" ? Why not command exe? And what is the purpose not using command line and not using the integration in eclipse which exists? What exactly is the problem with those options?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820330/how-to-run-maven-project-from-eclipse

Comment: Hey Khmarbaise, 

I just want to run like the way we execute from command prompt.

For example, If I have added any plugin ( i.e. tomact7) then to execute "mvn tomcat:run" command I must configured it in "Run As" so like wise for each new command I don't want to configure.

Hence I want to execute all the commands directly from/within eclipse itself.

Comment: I have already added the M2E plugin to my eclipse,hence I can able to create the maven project in eclipse

Comment: if you added m2e plugin to your eclipse you can directly goto Run As->maven build . it will maven clean and maven install it.

Answer (score 2):

Add m2e (maven to eclipse ) plugin to your eclipse. It will give the ability to run maven commands directly from eclipse like Run As -> Mavenclean or you can do Run As-> maven install.  If you want to do it all in one just goto Run AS-> maven Build and in the goals type " clean install" so that your project will be cleaned and installed.

If you don,t want to use this.. you can go for eclipse console.in the right most corner you can see a new icon click it ,you can see m2e console. by using the console you can use commands directly from the eclipse for the particular project

Comment: Hey! Obuli Sundar,

I am already using M2E plugin. I have updated my post with more details so kindly refer it again.

Comment: No... My requirement is different...

I don't want to configure the "Run AS" for each new command execution as said in my post.