# How to run Maven project in Eclipse by importing it from github

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I am new to Java and maven I just need to run this 
 https://github.com/att/XACML Maven project.

Any one please give me some guidelines as If I build this in Eclipse I get these errors.
I need to install `gpg` software as I don't know much about `gpg`, because I am new to this.

```
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.19.1:verify (integration-tests) @ att-xacml ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.5:sign (sign-artifacts) @ att-xacml ---
'gpg.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] ATT XACML 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT ........................... FAILURE [ 19.653 s]
[INFO] att-xacml .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] att-xacml-pip ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] att-xacml-pdp ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] xacml-test ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] xacml-rest ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] xacml-pdp-rest ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] xacml-pap-rest ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] xacml-pap-admin 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 05:54 min
```

Once that will work, I will need to know how to run:

```
mvn jetty:run-war
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part of the error message that matters is just *above* what you posted.
See for instance [att/XACML issue 30](https://github.com/att/XACML/issues/30):

```
[INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.5:sign (sign-artifacts) @ att-xacml ---
gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] ATT XACML .......................................... FAILURE [  2.712 s]
```

That error was resolved with  a Java update, so double-check which Java you are using in your Eclipse.

---

In the OP's case, the error is:

```
'gpg.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

That simply means you need to launch Eclipse from a CMD session where gpg.exe is recognized:

```
gpg.exe --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.29 (Gpg4win 2.3.0)
```

Check your `%PATH%` in the CMD:

```
set PATH
```

And adjust it accordingly:

```
set PATH=C:\path\to\gpg;%PATH%
```

Then launch Eclipse, and in it maven.

---

The OP adds:

> how I am able to access the console of local host?
>   Like where I can run this command (`mvn jetty:run-war`) and how.

See "[Is there any tool in eclipse to run maven commands directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27398373/6309)": assuming you have [m2e (M2Eclipse)](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) already installed with you Eclipse, you will be able to [define a maven "run configuration"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15634110/6309).

See more in "[Sonatype: Developing with Eclipse and Maven / 4.2. Running Maven Builds](https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/running-sect-running-maven-builds.html)".

[image: https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/figs/web/running_run-config.png]

For `mvn jetty:run` specifically, see "[how to run a web service maven project on jetty 8 from eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11720893/6309)".

Comment: I am not able to understand I just need to follow these steps.

Open a terminal window and cd to the XACML-PAP-REST subdirectory.

'mvn jetty:run-war'

By default it will be running at localhost:9090/pap

Comment: @AtherAbdulJabbar What step of https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/running-sect-running-maven-builds.html you don't understand?

Comment: yeah done but now I am stuck at this
[INFO] Started ServerConnector@53f7a906{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:9090}
[INFO] Started @121084ms
[INFO] Started Jetty Server

Comment: @AtherAbdulJabbar Please create a new question, with a screenshot of your current "run configuration". That will be easier to answer it there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51999676/unable-to-start-jetty-server